# How to properly implement the page control example

Tags: uiscrollview, xcode4.2, paging

How can i use the PageControl example to load multiple xib's as the pages. Is it possible to include an array to have the pages auto populate? Also is there a simpler way of coding this? The example coding is beyond me.